# 4-wire voltage sensing for DC load

Tags: voltage-measurement, dummy-load

I'm building an electronic DC load. I'd like to implement voltage sensing (4-wire sensing). I made this schematic:
[image]

Input voltage can be up to 60V, this circuit basically divides it by 6, and output voltages go to various parts of DC load (ADC, analog multiplier, opamps, etc.). It is not just about ADC, I need analog value of that voltage (so it is not possible to use 2-channel ADC and measure both inputs in software).
When SENSE+ and SENSE- are not connected, voltage is automatically measured at LOAD+ and LOAD- terminals.
When SENSE+ and SENSE- are connected, voltage is automatically measured at SENSE+ and SENSE- terminals.

My question is whether this implementation is OK, or there could be some potential problems, or is there a better way of doing it?

Another way I can think of is to use relay, second [MAX44241](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX44241-MAX44246.pdf), and switch relay manually in software/MCU. But I prefer "automatic switching".

**EDIT:**
I goofed up that opamp stage. I definitely should use instrumentation amplifier:
[image]

Comment: Frankly I don't get it, how this automatic switching is performed. Next thing is the high input impedance divider that will be affected by input bias current of the opamp.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič When SENSE wires are not connected, there is only voltage across LOAD terminals. That is input to opamp. When SENSE terminals are connected, it goes to opamp.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič MAX44241 has typical input bias current 300pA, so it should not be a problem.